# In a PHP session, how do I echo out a form value that has been filled out?

Tags: php, forms, session, if-statement, undefined-index

--Solution found--

The correct PHP code is a combination of the two answers provided below by user1175332 and shanethehat:

Correct HTML Code:

```
<?php session_start() ?>

<form method="post"  action="session7.php" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="book" value="" id="book"/> Book Box

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>


</form>
```

Correct PHP Code:

```
<?php session_start();
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['book'])) { 
    $_SESSION['book'] = $_POST['book']; 
} 
?>



<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['book']) && $_SESSION['book'] > 0)

{echo $_SESSION['book'] . ' Book Box(es)';}

else {echo '';}


?>
```

This works in an isolated test environment. Unfortunately it still doesn't work with the actual form I'm using, probably because of the javascript it contains.

----- Original Post -----

I have a form in which the user fills out a quantity for different items (1 of X, 4 of Y, etc.) Once the form is submitted, he is taken to the next page, where a price is shown based on the total quantity / volume (this part works thanks to the guys here at StackOverflow).

On the next page, I am trying to have every item that has been filled out (i.e. every item with a quantity greater than 0) be displayed. For instance, if the customer has 1 of X, 4 of Y, but 0 of Z, I want the next page to show:

1 X
4 Y

The form can be seen [here](http://dolphinexpress.com/js/quote-test.php). For some reason, I keep getting an "Undefined Index" error.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php session_start();
    if ($_POST && !empty($_POST['TOTAL'])) {
        $_SESSION['TOTAL'] = $_POST['TOTAL'];
    }

    /* this part is the first problematic part*/
    if ($_POST && !empty($_POST['PROD_SP_1.5'])) {
        $_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5'] = $_POST['PROD_SP_1.5'];
    }
?>
/* end of the first problematic part*/


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body>

/* this part is the second problematic part*/
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5'] > 0) {
        echo $_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5'] . 'Book Box';
    }
    else {
        echo '';
    }
?>
/* end of the second problematic part*/

<!-- This part posts the total volume in Cubic Feet-->
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL'])) {
        echo 'Your total volume is ' . round($_SESSION['TOTAL']) . ' Cubic Feet.';
    } else {
        echo 'You did not fill out any details. Please go back.';
    }
?>

<!-- End of volume posting -->

<br/><br/>

<!-- This part posts the correct price based on the total volume -->
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 250) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $1,899.00 based on 1 Section (up to     250CF).';
    } elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 500) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $3,349.00 based on 2 Sections (up to 500CF).';
    } elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 750) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $4,899.00 based on 3 Sections (up to 750CF).';
    } elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 1000) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $5,999.00 based on an exclusive 20ft Container.';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 1250) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $7,499.00 based on 5 Sections (up to     1,250CF).';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 1500) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $8,599.00 based on 6 Sections (up to 1,500CF).';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 1750) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $9,499.00 based on 7 Sections (up to     1,750CF).';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 2000) {
        echo 'The guaranteed price for door to door service is $9,999.00 based on an exclusive 40ft     Container.';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry, your total volume is too high to quote online. Please contact us to set up an on-    site survey: 1.877.430.1300';
    }
?>

<!-- end of price section -->


</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Undefined Index means your using the variable before its set, you should use `isset()` within your conditions or assign all variables with default values.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the session value has been set, because the condition further up the page means that it is possible for `$_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5']` to not exist:

```
/* this part is the second problematic part*/
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5']) && $_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5'] > 0) {
echo $_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5'] . 'Book Box';
}
```

You should also use `isset` rather than `empty` when checking id a value exists in the POST array:

```
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['PROD_SP_1.5'])) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion shanethehat. I updated the code, but still there's no output. It seems that the php code doesn't recognize when a quantity has been filled out on the form.

Comment: Thank you shanethehat for the update - still no luck. I will consult with the PHP programmer in my office and see if he can help. Will update the post here if he can.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you include `<?php session_start();?>` on every page? This is required if you want to use sessions
2. I see that you only set `$_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5']` if it's not empty. I suggest setting it to 0 if it is empty, or changing the test to `if (isset($_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5']) && $_SESSION['PROD_SP_1.5'] > 0)`

Comment: Hello, yes, I've included <?php session_start() ;?> on all pages. I tried what you and shanethehat suggested, and still the problem persists. This code gives no output

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Are you only using two pages? One with the form and another to display the results? If so, you can use $_POST instead of $_SESSION when printing the results

Comment: Thank you for the update - I tried with $_POST and still no luck. The form redirects the user to a different page based on selection he makes on the form, but essentially yes, there are only two pages (1 is the form page, and the other is one of the pages the user is directed to).